# No fail reason in logs when using Jest on Windows with Github Actions

Tags: node.js, windows, jestjs, github-actions

I'm trying to setup Github Actions to run our tests using Jest. The issue is, I don't have any error in the Actions logs when a test fail on Windows.

Here's my `.github/workflows/CI.yml`:

```
name: CI
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  Tests:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10]
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macOS-latest]
    steps:
    - run: git config --global core.autocrlf false
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm i -g yarn
    - name: yarn install and test
      run: |
        yarn config set ignore-engines true
        yarn
        yarn test --verbose=false
  Format:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
    - run: npm i -g yarn
    - name: yarn install and format
      run: |
        yarn config set ignore-engines true
        yarn
        yarn format:prettier
```

The `yarn test` runs`jest tests`.

And this Action output the following on Windows:

```
  yarn config set ignore-engines true
  yarn
  yarn test --verbose=false
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
yarn config v1.22.0
success Set "ignore-engines" to "true".
Done in 0.06s.
yarn install v1.22.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 43.23s.
yarn run v1.22.0
$ jest tests --verbose=false
FAIL tests/end-to-end.test.ts
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I've tryied with and without the `--verbose` flag but both output this:

```
FAIL tests/end-to-end.test.ts
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

And nothing more. There's not even the passing tests. I have no idea where this could come from.

Also, this only append on Windows. On Ubuntu & Mac, Jest has the correct output (succeeding tests and why this one failed).